# Java constructors, where do you place one time heavy initialization?

Tags: java, constructor

Should I place heavy initialization inside a constructor? one that access external resources and throws all sort of exceptions?
Logically, the initialization happens once and should be executed in the beginning of the class, but placing a lot of logic inside a constructor is not advised, some say it should only make simple assignments.
What do you think is best?

Comment: For heavy initialization you could consider dependency injection. Like Spring for example: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html. Check out the book "Spring in Action".

Comment: Maybe lookup "Factory Pattern". If the object needs information from various dbs etc. you would not want all the dependencies in the class. You can encapsulate those in a Factory and keep them away from the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor should only construct the object for use. If the object in question requires connections etc there should be public facing methods that the caller can invoke and those methods can throw exceptions that the caller could in turn handle.

i.e.

Connecting to a db
You create a connection
set its keys/values/parameters 
You then call connect.

The reason for using patterns like this is that you may want to construct an object ahead of time without having it do all sorts of heavy lifting etc.

If you have a look at 99% of Java built in libraries they use this pattern where the constructor returns a new instance of the given object.

What you then decide to do with the object is up to you.

If you object requires information to be setup those should be passed in to the constructor.

For example you could pass in a file location/path into the constructor the object would then store the location in an encapsulated variable for example.

But when the file is to be read a separate method called load or something like that should be called. That method will check if the file exists and read the contents.

This allows the load method to throw exceptions and potentially have retries etc which could all be run on a separate thread if need be. Doing that kind of thing in a Constructor is not advisable.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer might depend on what you mean by "heavy".

If it means "lengthy computations", you might consider doing them in a background thread and exposing a service to make them available when they're needed.

If it means "lots of stuff to initialize", it might be a sign that your object has too much state and needs to be refactored.

Does every instance of that class need its own copy of that data?  Or can it be static and initialized once for all classes?  If it's the latter, perhaps you can do it in a static block.

is it read only state or writable?  That will be important for thread safety.  Have you synchronized access properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static factory class, which inits heavy resources once and provides access to it via static method.